# how get echoed string from php into android studio

Tags: php, android-studio, mysqli

ive created a method which connects to a PHP file and I'm trying to use whats echoed from that in my android studio project

```
$checkquery = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE PATIENT_EMAIL = ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

    if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$checkquery))
    {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $exits = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

        if($exits>0)
        {
            echo "EXI";
        }
        else
        {
            $addquery = "INSERT INTO PATIENT(PATIENT_EMAIL,PATIENT_NAME,PATIENT_SURNAME,PATIENT_ADDRESS,PATIENT_CONTACT,PATIENT_IMAGE,PATIENT_PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            $hasspwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

            if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$addquery))
            {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssbs",$email,$name,$surname,$address,$contact,$image,$hasspwd);

                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                echo "done";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed";
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
```

here's the part of the PHP code.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://lamp.ms.wits.ac.za/home/s2241186/signup.php";
    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("type",type);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("name",name);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("email",email);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("surname",surname);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("address",null);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password",password);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("contact",phone);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("image",null);

    String queryurl = urlBuilder.build().toString();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(queryurl).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                final String result = response.body().toString();

                CreateAccount.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("EXI"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, "User already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           moveToSelfie();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

my code keeps moving to the else statement of the result.equals()
is there some way to return exactly what was echoed from the PHP file?
cause I'm lost as how to do so